# Sails.js log transport depend on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, sails.js, logentries

I have a Sails.js project that I would like to add LogEntries support for event logging. However I would like to use LogEntries only in some environments.

For example, in development I don't want to fill the logs with development garbage.

```
// config/log.js

var logentries = require('le_node');
var log = (sails.config.environment === 'development') ? sails.log : logentries.logger({
  token: 'YOUR_TOKEN'
});

module.exports.log = {
  log: {
    custom: log
  }
}
```

But with this I get an error that the `sails` is not defined. This is because `sails` object is not available in configuration files such as `config/log.js`. So how can use a custom log transport depending on the environment in this case?

Comment: wrap a function around it so you can pass in config from a place that has it. `var logger=require("log").log("dev")`, which should return a function, the one you used to get without the extra trailing paren call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end what seems correct was not modify the `config/log.js` file directly but to modify the environment configuration file:

```
// config/env/production.js

var logentries = require('le_node');
var log = logentries.logger({
  token: 'YOUR_TOKEN'
});

module.exports.log = {
  log: {
    custom: log
  }
}
```

This way only the production environment will have the custom logging.

Answer (score 0):

In all config modules, I find that you can't just write `sails.config.someModule`. Just go with the typical `var someModule = require(./someModule)`. Much more easier that way.

Comment: I've read that it's not recommended to require config files from other config files (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622955/accessing-config-variables-from-other-config-files)