# reference sails config outside module.exports

Tags: sails.js

How can I use sails.config outside the module.exports? I'm trying to pass sails.config variables to another object, something like below;

```
var foo = new Foo(sails.config.myconf.myVar);

module.exports {
  bar : function(){
    // Use foo here
    foo.blah();
  }
};
```

(Same question also asked in a comment in this [Create config variables in sails.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267706/create-config-variables-in-sails-js) See @jreptak comment)

Answer (score 1):

Each files of Sails config is a module then if you want to use it, you just have to import it.

Here is an example to import Sails connections of `sails.config.connections` module.
**Be careful about the path of the module in the `require`, it must be relative.**

```js
var connections = require('../../config/connections');
```

Answer (score 1):

This was not possible in Sails v0.9. However, this is now possible in Sails v0.10 onwards.

Here's the specific issue on github: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1672

So now you can do something like this:

```
//MyService.js
var client = new Client(sails.config.client);
module.exports = {
   myMethod: function(callback){
      client.doSomething();
   }
}
```

If you're stuck with Sails v0.9, I would recommend that you follow the workaround specified in the github issue:

```
 //MyService.js
var client;
module.exports = function(){
  client = client || new Client(sails.config.client);
  return {
    myMethod: function(){
      client.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
//SomeController.js
module.exports = {
   list: function(req,res){
      MyService().myMethod();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, if you want to access `sails.config` params you have to create a custom hook http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks and do your 'magic' in it